# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.4.3 error

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

There are some similar results in the search but seem to have a always a different reason.
The full error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:679)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:693)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.parallelize(JavaSparkContext.scala:134)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.parallelize(JavaSparkContext.scala:146)
>       at DataMiningUtil.getFrequentSequencesForEventsPerUser(DataMiningUtil.java:71)
>       at Main.method(Main.java:62)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:16)
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.4.3
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:56)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:550)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala)

In my POM I don't even have a reference to a jackson version 2.4.3

[Resolved dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUbNI.png)

The libraries I added in my POM are

[Maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IQKK.png)

I fiddled around a little bit with he libraries by excluding some of them but nothing seemed to help.

Here the code that produces the issue.

```
JavaRDD<List<List<Integer>>> sequences = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
                  Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(3)),
                  Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(3, 2), Arrays.asList(1, 2)),
                  Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(5)),
                  Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(6))
                ), 2);


        PrefixSpan prefixSpan = new PrefixSpan().setMinSupport(0.5).setMaxPatternLength(5);
        PrefixSpanModel<Integer> model = prefixSpan.run(sequences);

        for (PrefixSpan.FreqSequence<Integer> freqSeq: model.freqSequences().toJavaRDD().collect()) {
            System.out.println(freqSeq.javaSequence() + ", " + freqSeq.freq());
        }
```

It is the same as on the spark website

Any idea what I need to do to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:2.0.2` dependency instead of `org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:1.5.1`? You include Spark core that uses Scala 2.11 and has version 2.0.2 and Spark ML that uses Scala 2.10 and has version 1.5.1.

Comment: Maybe `jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.4.4` causes the problem?

Comment: Also try `mvn dependency:tree` so see where Jackson 2.4.x is popping up.

Comment: I tried the org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:2.0.2 but get the same error. Also did the depency tree but get no jar whith even version 2.4.3. Also excluded the jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.4.4 but still same error

Comment: @BenHur can you share a small sample project to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @AntonOkolnychyi The code has been added. It is the same as on http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html

Comment: @BenHur what are the "librec" and "spmf" libraries? I managed to run the code without any problems using just Spark Core and ML and even with all the dependencies from the picture expect "librec" and "spmf". Can you provide their full names?

Comment: @AntonOkolnychyi Librec is a java recommender library (http://www.librec.net/). SPMF is a data mining library (http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/). But even after removing them from my POM I still have the same issue.